# EntityManager.find(MyClass.class, id) returns null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

My entitymanager.find() gives nullpointerexception, there is a row in the database with the id provided.

```
@Entity
public class ForumCategory implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column (name="title")
private String title;
@Column (name="datecreated")
private Date created;
@Column (name="dateupdated")
private Date updated;  
@Column (name="createdby")
private String createdBy;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private Set<ForumThread> threads;
```

this is the find method

```
public ForumCategory find(Long id) {
    ForumCategory category = em.find(ForumCategory.class, id);
    return category;
}
```

i have tried using but still error.

```
em.createQuery("SELECT obj FROM ForumCategory obj WHERE obj.id=1")
```

i am using MySqlWorkbench and when i run "select * from forumcategory where id=1" it returns the correct row.

Comment: NPE on calling `em.find` has nothing to do with the row not being there. Most likely the EntityManager is null. You will need to show more about your configuration (persistence.xml, EntityManager - are you using container injection, creating it yourself), the runtime environment (i.e. stanalone, server). For some reason the EntityManager is not being created, if it is the case the EM is null. Also post the stacktrace.

Comment: ooh, i was using the debugger in Netbeans but didnt see it. You are right that it is null i will look deeper in my code to try and figure out where the error lies. thank you @peeskillet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `entityManager` is `null`. That's why you get a `NullPointerException` when you call `em.find()` method.